# Notification : "update required"

Tags: sync, aquaris, bq

Since the last update on my Bq Aquaris 4.5 (Ubuntu 15.04 OTA-8), there is this notification each time I turn on my phone: "Only local contacts will be editable until the contact sync upgrade is complete ".

With what my contacts are supposed to synchronize ?

Regards,
Dudukun

Comment: i also have this problem, and i can not edit the current contacts... i think that buteo (the new sync) might not be working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I guess they mean 'sync with a google account' which is the only possibility of syncing (at least on my bq Aquaris).  If you do not use this functionality, I wonder why this message appears, as no sync will take place.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot!

I also had this problem and after i done a reboot, the phone started a upgrade in next boot and fixed the problem... So the answer is **reboot**